# Showcaseview NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, showcaseview

I added [showcaseview](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) jar into my project and use it like this

```
    ShowcaseView.ConfigOptions co = new ShowcaseView.ConfigOptions();
    co.hideOnClickOutside = true;

    ViewTarget target = new ViewTarget(R.id.button_start_game, this);
    ShowcaseView sv = ShowcaseView.insertShowcaseView(target, this, R.string.showcase_main_title, R.string.showcase_main_message, co);
    sv.setOnShowcaseEventListener(this);
```

but I have exception

```
02-05 20:03:25.495: E/AndroidRuntime(25767): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 20:03:25.495: E/AndroidRuntime(25767): Process: com...., PID: 25767
02-05 20:03:25.495: E/AndroidRuntime(25767): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.github.espiandev.showcaseview.R$styleable
02-05 20:03:25.495: E/AndroidRuntime(25767):    at com.espian.showcaseview.ShowcaseView.<init>(ShowcaseView.java:105)
02-05 20:03:25.495: E/AndroidRuntime(25767):    at com.espian.showcaseview.ShowcaseView.<init>(ShowcaseView.java:97)
02-05 20:03:25.495: E/AndroidRuntime(25767):    at com.espian.showcaseview.ShowcaseView.insertShowcaseViewInternal(ShowcaseView.java:825)
02-05 20:03:25.495: E/AndroidRuntime(25767):    at com.espian.showcaseview.ShowcaseView.insertShowcaseView(ShowcaseView.java:854)
02-05 20:03:25.495: E/AndroidRuntime(25767):    at com...MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82)
```

82 line has

```
ShowcaseView sv = ShowcaseView.insertShowcaseView(target, this, R.string.showcase_main_title, R.string.showcase_main_message, co);
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a rookie Developer and I always seem to get stuck on things like this...

The solution is to not use a JAR, add the Showcaseview project as a library instead.

I solved this same issue by the following steps:

1. Import "Main" project that is in the "library" folder into my workspace from
   https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView
2. Right click the imported project from Step 1 and click properties>Android and check the "is library" box
   ![enter image description here][2]
3. Right click the project you want to use Showcaseview in and click properties>Android and click "Add"
4. Select the project from Step 1 and Click "OK" (Note: I have renamed mine to "Showcase" yours should be "Main" if you got the project from the Github link above)
5. Click Apply
6. Clean and Build

Enjoy less squiggly red lines!!!

I would post screen shots but this is my first SO post...

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same error. As because i haven't included nineoldandroid library. Just download this library from http://nineoldandroids.com/ and add this library to your Project. Your Error resolves surely