# ShowcaseView Legacy NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, showcaseview

I am trying to use hand gestures with ShowcaseView. My project's target sdk is 21, the minimum sdk is 9, the device I am using for development is 4.4.4 and I am developing in eclipse. I have downloaded the legacy branch. I am using the following code:

```
svConfig = new ShowcaseView.ConfigOptions();
svConfig.hideOnClickOutside = false;
svConfig.showcaseId = 1;
svBuilder = new ShowcaseViewBuilder(this);
svBuilder.setConfigOptions(svConfig);
svBuilder.animateGesture(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f);
svBuilder.build();
```

At a different attempt I tried this without any success:

```
sv = ShowcaseView.insertShowcaseView(R.id.logo_screen, this, "How to scroll down", " ", svConfig);
sv.animateGesture(200, 500, 200, 0);
```

My library consists of this project (https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/tree/legacy), I added the jar appropriate jar files (*mockito-all-1.9.5.jar*, *nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar*, *robolectric-2.2-20130909.210745-40-jar-with-dependencies.jar* and *android-support-v4.jar*).  
Apart from those libraries I tried newer versions of these. 
In order to be specific I am mentioning the md5sum string just to ensure that I am working with the appropriate libraries:
*android-support-v4.jar*: ed257a47cae11af1a55614055b879947 
*mockito-all-1.9.5.jar*: 50faa79d126d0213ab14ccb112a8b76d 
*nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar*: d719629ae7c443ed75566ef241bc835d 
*robolectric-2.2-20130909.210745-40-jar-with-dependencies.jar*: bcb3d8dc757165ef3e5a70c717bc9c41 
**The following are different versions of some libraries:** 
*robolectric-2.3.jar*: 578aaaf81a7ea7484b89cc54c928a80f 
*nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar*: 1ee7c24e16eaca1f6278abc7dc104e1b 
The Ctrl+Space in Eclipse finds all the classes and the methods but I still receive "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.espian.showcase.ShocaseViewBuilder".
How can I fix it?
PS: These suggestions ([Showcaseview NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585302/showcaseview-noclassdeffounderror)) didn't fix my problem.

Comment: After a lot of tries without success I added the packages as they exist to my project and it working fine with some modifications!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Gradle-based project, then you can add SCV as a dependency directly:

```
compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.0.0'
```

If you're using Maven (but not Gradle), you can add the APKlib as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview</groupId>
  <artifactId>library</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0</version>
  <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```